# CreateUserWizard step changing issue after account creation

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-membership, createuserwizard

I want to change the createuserwizard.step= start if the mail sending fails and not to go to successful creation step.

```
                 catch (SmtpException ex)
    {
       Membership.DeleteUser(textboxemail.Text.Trim());
       Literal errorMessage=(Literal) CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("ErrorMessage");
       errorMessage.Text = "Account creation failed due to email notification."+ ex.Message + " errorcode" +ex.StatusCode + "; inner exception; " + ex.InnerException;
       CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.StepType = WizardStepType.Start;
    }
```

but the exception says the steptype can't be changed. So how to do this. I mean to stop from going to success step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting that exception because you need to use the [Wizard.MoveTo method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.wizard.moveto.aspx).

Like this:

```
CreateUserWizard1.MoveTo(WizardStep1);
```

Where "WizardStep1" is the ID of the `asp:WizardStep` that you want to go back to (the "start" step).